# Including controllers in Twig templates, rather than other templates

Tags: php, templates, twig

As I have understood, the main design idea of templating engines like Twig is to remove all PHP code from views, and to have the controller that renders a view have set all parameters that are necessary in that view.

However, imagine that a view consists of different "blocks": a header, a footer, a shopping cart and a productlist. You could have the order_controller.php check whether or not the customer is logged in (because if not, the header doesn’t contain the link "Log off"), as well as fetch a list of all available products (to show them in the product block), as well as fetch the contents of the shopping cart in the $_SESSION (to show them in the shoppingcart block).

However, it might be more interesting to have the order_controller only fetch one thing: the list of products. The view that will be rendered by the controller would then contain different includes for the other blocks (header, footer and shopping cart), but they wouldn’t include their views. They would include other controllers (showheader_controller, showfooter_controller and showcart_controller), which in turn would render their own single blocks (showheader_controller would only render the header-view etc…). In short: you would include controllers that render views in the main view. The logic that would check whether or not the customer is logged in would then be showheader_controller, for the simple reason that the header view is the only view that needs to know this. The logic that load the contents of the shopping cart from $_SESSION would be the showcart_controller, because the cart-view is the only view that needs to have access to this data, etc...

This way, you could have tons of controllers that all show the header, but the instead of having each controller repeat the logic to check whether or not the customer is logged in, you would only have it in one place (the controller that renders the header-view).
If there were a Twig function to include any external source on that spot in the view, the problem would be fixed (since I could just include the other controllers), but as it is it only allows for the including of other templates (that cannot have PHP-logic in them, otherwise it would kinda defeat the purpose).

The way I fix this now is to have the order_controller have this logic:

- Fetch the productlist
- Start the buffering of the outputstream (ob_start())
- Include the controller that renders the header (showheader_controller)
- Store the contents of the buffer in a variable $headerView.
- Clean up the buffer
- Start the buffering of the outputstream (ob_start())
- Include the controller that renders the shopping cart (showcart_controller)
- Store the contents of the buffer in a variable $cartView.
- Clean up the buffer
- Rinse and repeat...

In the view,  I print the contents of the set variables:

```
{{ headerView | raw }}
```

The raw-filter has to be added, because the headerView variable contains html-tags.

It works perfectly, but it’s not exactly “neat”.

My question: would there be a better way to achieve this strategy?

Answer (score 3):

First, this can be simplified by implementing the MVC separation better. The controller's job is pretty much solely to react to *events* and poke the model into doing appropriate things in reaction to this event. It is not the controller's job to hold hands with the view, nor is the view entirely dependent upon the controller.

The model is your core application, *modeling* all the things your application is supposed to do. The view's job is to visualize what is going on in the application, to give the user something to interact with. The controller is just a little glue between the user and your application, something that lets the user *control* the application.

As such, the controller reacts to events like *"user visited homepage"*, triggers necessary events in the model, which causes the view to update to represent the new state of the application. The view can do whatever it needs to do. The view is not just a Twig template. The view can talk back to the model to get more information. In the end it is not the controller that needs to send necessary data to the Twig template, it's the view that needs to set the necessary data for the template before it renders it. Less code in controllers, more code in the view.

If you want to make this more modular, you can define custom Twig tags or functions which may fetch the necessary data from wherever it needs fetching. For instance:

```
<div class="head">{{ user_login_status() }}</div>
```

`user_login_status` is a Twig extension function which can talk to the model to get the data necessary to display the status.

Hope you get the idea.